# How to add an element to every row in a data frame?

Tags: python, dataframe, separator

I have three types of columns in my dataframe: numeric, string and datetime.

I need to add the element | to the end of every value as a separator

I have tried:

```
df['column'] = (df['column']+ '|')
```

but it does not work for the datetime columns and I have to add .astype(str) to the numeric columns which may result in formatting issues later.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Are you trying to create a csv file with `|` delimiter ?

Comment: @Rakesh actually, yes! can I do it directly from excel?

Answer (score 0):

you can use DataFrame.to_csv() with sep="|", if you want to create a csv.

further documentation :
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure why you would want to do this but if you want to make a CSV file with `|` as the delimiter, you can set that in the `df.to_csv('out.csv', sep='|')` method. I think a cleaner way of doing this would be to use a *lambda* function:

```
df['column'] = df['column'].apply(lambda x: f"{x}|")
```

You will always have to add `.astype(str)` though...

Answer (score 0):

This may help you in this case:

```
df['column'] = df['column'].astype(str) + "|"
```